# Putting names from a file into an array is causing an infinite loop

Tags: java, arrays, text

I have a text file "names" which contains 10 names, each name on its own line. What I want to do is put these names into an array "anArray". Just to check that I'm doing an alright job, I outputted a line as you can see.

Here's the code I used to try to do that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    { 
        File file=new File("names.txt");
        Scanner my_input= new Scanner(file);
        String [] anArray;
        anArray = new String[10];
        String a = my_input.nextLine();
        while(my_input.hasNextLine())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
            {
                while (!(a.equals("\n")))
                {
                    anArray[i] = a;
                    System.out.println("Element" + i + "of the array is: " + anArray[i]);

                }
                i++;
                a=my_input.next();
            }
        }
        my_input.close();      
    }
```

However this code fails, what happens is "Element 0 of the array is: name 1" is outputted an infinite amount of times, "name 1" being the first name in the text file. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, could anybody enlighten me?

Comment: What is `while (!(a.equals("\n")))` intended to do? Because you don't update `a` in that `while` loop, which should be a **red flag**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch To separate the names into different array elements. I thought that when the name ends and thus an "\n" is encountered by the scanner, i would increase by one.

Comment: You are not advancing the scanner in the innermost while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have an infinite loop on your inner `while` loop, you don't update `a` so that will loop forever once entered. I think you wanted to check that `i` is less than `10` **and** your input still has more lines. You can do that with a singe loop. I would also prefer a `try-with-resources` over explicitly closing. And you can guard against empty lines with `String.isEmpty()`. Something like,

```
File file = new File("names.txt");
try (Scanner my_input = new Scanner(file)) {
    String[] anArray = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && my_input.hasNextLine(); i++) {
        String line = my_input.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        anArray[i] = line;
        System.out.printf("Element %d of the array is: %s%n", i, anArray[i]);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the function of the try as I haven't seen it before. A google search says "exception handling".  What exception would this be in this case? Also, the "continue;" line, does that mean that 'i" will be incremented when it encounters that?

Comment: @YakSalTafri **`FileNotFoundException`**. Also [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the innermost while loop never changes, so the contents will repeat indefinitely.

Something to change the value of the phrase

```
while (!(a.equals("\n")))
```

must occur in the body of the loop, otherwise it will stay true if it starts out true.

Comment: Ah, I moved "a=my_input.next();" so that the "a" changes within the loop, and now the last 9 names are outputted, but the first one isn't, and all of them say "Element 0 of the Array", so it seems like the i isn't incrementing. It also sees one name separated by a space "John William" as two names, "John" and "William".

Comment: From what you commented, it sounds to me like you are now aware enough of the issues to fix this code to your satisfaction.